# Using multiple versions of RequireJS

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs

I have a web app built with Dojo 1.7.2, using RequireJS to load individual modules with AMD.  I'd like to add a slightly customized copy of the ACE code editor version 0.2.0, which is about 9 months old and uses an earlier, incompatible version of RequireJS to load itself.

Really I'd just like to include the different JavaScript files (Dojo and ACE) without having a namespace collision (on global functions `declare` and `require` which is something that RequireJS is designed to help prevent anyway).  I'd like to do this without further customization of either project.  Is that even possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ace's authors recommend using the newest version from the master branch which should be compatible with recent RequireJS.

BTW, could you post somewhere how you managed to run Dojo 1.7.2 with RequireJS?

Comment: Dojo and RequireJS are documented here: http://requirejs.org/docs/dojo.html and here: http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/learn-more-about-amd

Comment: @emackey, thanks. It seems Dojo's loader is the way to go for now.